Video cannot be loaded of ImageKit
I am trying to use ImageKit in my project. I have started a simple flow that only has the upload video feature. I have a backend containing only one file index.js not a created frontend rather I was testing it with the Postman as in SS
The problem is when I upload the video the backend sends a url response. When I click on this URL response it opens a video but won't play it it shows a blank screen as shown in SS

When I logged in to the ImageKit and went to that path I got this error and show in the SS below
The uploaded image shows that the video is unsupported but I uploaded an mp4 file which is playing on my system

Here is the postman ss that indicates that I request a post request and the video is uploaded to image it

This is my index.js file where I have created a simple route that uploads the video on ImageKit

I think that this is the issue of the ImageKit itself.

I had the same issue but with the python SDK. The video file came from the client, then it was read from a stream and passed as the file argument to the SDK's upload method. But it turned out that the type of the file was wrong. It was bytes but SDK accepts binary, base64 or strings (external urls). When I converted my file in bytes into base64 and then passed to the SDK, the file was uploaded successfuly.
Python example:
from base64 import b64encode

...

contents = await _file.read() # this is bytes
file = b64encode(contents)

client.upload(file=file, ...)

...

